# Gnuplot epslatex files output path problem

Tags: path, gnuplot

I have a problem in Gnuplot.
When I set the output filename with a relative path to save the `.tex` and `.eps` files in a different folder, the relative path is also included in the `\includegraphics` command in the `.tex` file.

For example, if I set the output file to be two levels above the current directory:

```
set terminal epslatex color size 6, 3
# ...
set output "../../filename.tex"
# ...
```

The `\includegraphics` command keeps that path when the file is already two levels above and searches two extra levels above of that directory instead of searching in the current directory:

```
% ...
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{../../filename}}%
% ...
```

It would be great to fix this issue in future versions, allowing to set the output path and file name (that appears in `\includegraphics` command) separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work-around:

Instead of including the full path (or relative path) in the file name, set it temporarily as your working directory:

```
 olddir = system("pwd")
 cd '../..'
 set output "filename.tex"
 plot <whatever>
 cd olddir
```

Comment: just to mention: under Windows it would be `olddir = system("chdir")`

Comment: @Ethan Thanks, it works, I had no idea I could use commands like `cd`. It's not the ideal solution but a good workaround.